# 0 - 1 data with asymptote: Which distribution/type of model

Tags: nonlinear-regression, ratio, percentage, beta-regression

I'm analysing data on degradation over time. Degradation has to be expressed as percent. Therefore I use betaregression.
However, we repeated to measured degradation after 100% degradation, therefore there'll be an asymptote to 100%. Since we only have 3 repicates per time point and 4-6 timepoints, I'd like to keep the model simple and not go into non-linear models. Also, I need to calculate half-life of degradation. With the betaregression I could do this using Monte Carlo simulations to get CIs.
Do you have any adive for me? Thanks!